# Why can I access overridden subclass methods from the superclass?

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

Why does `method()` call the overridden subclass `method2` instead of `method2` in the `BaseClass`?

```
public class BaseClass {
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("method() called");
        method2();
    }
    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("method2() called");
    }
}

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {
    public void method2(){
        System.out.println("method2() from BaseClass");
    }
}


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildClass obj = new ChildClass();
        obj.method();
    }
}
```

Comment: because that is how inheritance works?

Comment: Because of [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20dynamic%20dispatch,(OOP)%20languages%20and%20systems.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you come from the C++ corner:**

- all instance methods (non-static) in Java are `virtual`.
- All class methods (static) are NOT.

This is why your case happens.

This is also, why the Java compiler will complain (warn) that if you access a static method via an object, that you should call via the distinct class, because calls to the "static method of a object" could be ambiguous, because it could be two static methods with the same signature that get called.

**Extending your Example:**

```
package stackoverflow.staticcalls;

public class BaseClass {

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("method() called");
        method2();
    }
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("method2() called");
    }



    static public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("BaseClass.sayHello()");
    }

}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.staticcalls;

public class ChildClass extends BaseClass {

    public void method2() { // compiler warning: The method method2() of type ChildClass should be tagged with @Override since it actually overrides a superclass method
        System.out.println("method2() from BaseClass");
    }

    public void originalCallToBaseMethod2() {
        super.method2(); // will run BaseClass.method2()
    }



    static public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("ChildClass.sayHello()");
    }

}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.staticcalls;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final ChildClass obj = new ChildClass();
        System.out.println("\nCalling obj.method(); ...");
        obj.method();

        System.out.println("\nCalling obj.sayHello(); ...");
        obj.sayHello(); // compiler warning: The static method sayHello() from the type ChildClass should be accessed in a static way

        System.out.println("\nCalling ChildClass.sayHello(); ...");
        ChildClass.sayHello(); // the proper call

        System.out.println("\nCalling BaseClass.sayHello(); ...");
        BaseClass.sayHello(); // but you can also explpicitly call the other method

        System.out.println("\nCalling obj.originalCallToBaseMethod2(); ...");
        obj.originalCallToBaseMethod2(); //
    }

}
```

Here you see the examples to what I said.

**Note:** In the last call in Main.main() we still can call BaseClass.method2(), but not directly. We have to be within ChildClass to do that, and it's done via the `super` keyword/reference.

**A little off-topic note, to complete addressing patterns:**
If you're inside an inner class and need to call to a overshadowed name in the outer class, you can use `Outer.this.method()`:

```
package stackoverflow.staticcalls;

import stackoverflow.staticcalls.OuterInner.Outer.Inner;

public class OuterInner {

    class Outer {

        void method() {
            System.out.println("OuterInner.Outer.method()");
        }

        class Inner {

            void method() {
                System.out.println("OuterInner.Outer.Inner.method()");
            }

            void callOuter() {
                Outer.this.method();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final OuterInner oi = new OuterInner();
        final Outer outer = oi.new Outer();
        final Inner inner = outer.new Inner();

        System.out.println("\nCalling inner.method(); ...");
        inner.method();

        System.out.println("\nCalling inner.callOuter(); ...");
        inner.callOuter();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the concept of Runtime polymorphism (Dynamic Method Dispatch). Because you are assigning the object (instance) of `ChildClass` to `obj` reference variable, it will call the `method` of child class.

Always the method of the class whose instance is created gets called first. If that method is not present in that particular child class, then the parent's inherited method gets called.